# How I can enable "PayPal Pro" in my account?

Tags: paypal, checkout

I have a business account of PayPal. But for my store I have implemented  "PayPal Pro" option for payment.

So for the same I need to enable "Paypal Pro" in my account and need below mentioned details :

api username
api password
api signature

I have tested with another paypal sandbox account there was option to enable Pro in front of each account.

But now I want to change the mode to LIVE and want to use main account "Pro" credentials in website so that users can make payment through "PayPal Pro".

So please suggest for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to apply for Pro and get it approved on your account.  Is your account based in the US, UK, or Canada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was certificate issues. I have asked PayPal support and generated a new certificate. And its started working.